# PostgreSQL trigger and stored procedure not kicking in

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, triggers, plpgsql

My goal is to compute and persist a certain value before an update happens to a row in my table.

I created the trigger and the function, I don't get any errors but the function doesn't seem to be kicking in. Where am I going wrong?

The procedure

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION foo() returns trigger as
  $BODY$
  DECLARE
  BEGIN
    NEW.geomtry := st_transform(st_pointfromtext('POINT(' || NEW.af_lon || ' ' || NEW.af_lat || ')', 4326), 32643);
    return NEW;
  END;
  $BODY$
language plpgsql;
```

The trigger to trigger the method before an update happens

```
CREATE TRIGGER foo_trigger BEFORE UPDATE ON foo_table FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE foo();
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "*doesn't seem to be kicking in*". What statement are you running that you expect will kick off the trigger

Comment: By 'kicking in', I meant, when an update to a row in the table is triggered from the app, the value that needs to be computed and persisted before the actual update happens is not happening.

Comment: And which statement are you running that should fire the trigger?

Comment: The UPDATE statement. Eg: UPDATE foo_table set lat = 12, lon =90 where id = 1; So, my idea is, before this statement is persisted, the geometry should be calculated and set in the corresponding row.

Comment: When you do an update are the new values for lat and lon actually being stored in the database?

Comment: You may have a typo in your trigger: "NEW.geomtry". Check the column name.

Answer (score 1):

You spelled "geometry" incorrectly in your stored proc. Make sure it is spelled consistently in your table and stored proc.